# How can I synchronize processes started in different TMUX panes?

Tags: shell-script, tmux, synchronization, process-management

Consider this:

```
tmux split-window -d program1
program2 # this program depends on some side effects produced by program1
```

In this case, `program2` will start before `program1` is ready. `program1` will send signals/output when it has produced side-effects that can be consumed by `program2`.

My question: How can I write a shell script that will wait until `program1` is ready before starting `program2`?

Observation: `program2` does not consume `program1` output, so this is not solved by connecting the processes with a pipe.

Comment: Could you explain exactly how can the state of program1 (*ready* or *not ready yet*) be determined? And how exactly program1 sends those signals to program2? This can be useful because what you can do is make a script that looks for those signals, and only start program2 when those signals are detected. In any case if the circumstances permit it, it would be better if program2 itself deals with it. (for example. It goes to sleep until the signals wake it up)

Comment: I just found the answer

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash). In the end, it was not TMUX solution(initially I tought tmux would have some mechanism to syncronize the processes running in its panes)

The answer is using named pipes. Since `program1` sends output when it is ready, all I need is something like this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
tmux split-window -d "program1 > /tmp/pipe 2>&1"
signal=`cat /tmp/pipe`
program2 # This will only run after program1 has output something
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like [FLOM (Free LOck Manager)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flom/) should allow you to execute something like:

```
tmux split-window -d "flom -- program1"
flom -- program2 # this program depends on some side effects produced by program1
```

if "program1" starts before "program2" the expected behavior will be:

1. flom will create a logical resource and lock it exclusively for "program1"
2. flom will enqueue on the same logical resource for "program2" and wait until "program1" termination.